# Jquery UI dialog not working with Gmap in Ipad

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, jquery-ui-dialog

So weird this bug...

My site is https://www.merchantsbar.com/index.php
If you click "contact" at bottom of the page, or "sign up" on left, a jquery ui dialog shd popup. 
It works for all browsers I tested, except in ipad. Dialog is hidden after the animation. Pls go test it if you have an ipad.

I hunt down the problem & realized its google map causing the problem. Once the function is fired, the dialog is lost (keep in mind ipad is so far the only one giving me proble, even iphone works!).

Thanks in advance!

```
function initialize(canvas, AC, field_Lat, field_Lng, readonly, search_area){ 
    var Lat = Number($("#"+field_Lat).val()) == NaN ? $("#"+field_Lat).val() : 40.7399709 ;
    var Lng = Number($("#"+field_Lng).val()) == NaN ? $("#"+field_Lng).val() : -73.6135758 ;

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(Lat, Lng); // LatLng
    var options = {
        zoom: 11,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(canvas), options); // MAP
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); //GEOCODER

    if (readonly==true){ marker = new google.maps.Marker({ map: map }); } // readonly 
    else{ 
        if (search_area==true){ var distanceWidget = new DistanceWidget(map); } // SEARCH_AREA
        else{ marker = new google.maps.Marker({ map: map, draggable: true }); } // non-search_area
        autocomplete(AC, field_Lat, field_Lng); 
        geocodeReverse(AC, field_Lat, field_Lng); 
    } 
    marker.setPosition(latlng);
}

function autocomplete(AC, field_Lat, field_Lng){    
    $("#"+AC).autocomplete({
        //This bit uses the geocoder to fetch address values
        source: function(request, response){
            geocoder.geocode( {'address': request.term }, function(results, status){
                response($.map(results, function(item){
                    return {
                        label:  item.formatted_address,
                        value: item.formatted_address,
                        latitude: item.geometry.location.lat(),
                        longitude: item.geometry.location.lng()
                    }
                }));
            })
        },
        //This bit is executed upon selection of an address
        select: function(event, ui){
            $("#"+field_Lat).val(ui.item.latitude);
            $("#"+field_Lng).val(ui.item.longitude);
            var location = new google.maps.LatLng(ui.item.latitude, ui.item.longitude);
            marker.setPosition(location);
            map.setCenter(location);
        }
    });         
}

function geocodeReverse(AC, field_Lat, field_Lng){ 
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(){
        geocoder.geocode({'latLng' : marker.getPosition()}, function(results, status){
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
                if (results[0]){
                    $('#'+field_Lat).val(marker.getPosition().lat());
                    $('#'+field_Lng).val(marker.getPosition().lng());
                    $('#'+AC).val(results[0].formatted_address);
                    $("#Se_latitude, #Se_longitude").focus(); // inter-linked to validateField();
                    $("#"+field_Lat+", #"+field_Lng+", #"+AC).blur();
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

... later ...

```
$(".dialog").each(function(){
    var this_ID = this.id;
    $(this).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        width: "auto",
        show: {
            effect: "slide",
            duration: 400
        },
        hide: {
            effect: "slide",
            duration: 400
        }, 
        open: function(){ $('.ui-widget-overlay').on('click', function(){ $("#"+this_ID).dialog('close'); }); }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

force 3d acceleration with css3...

```
.ui-dialog * {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```